# Convert WSGIRequest to JSON

Tags: python, django, httprequest

While making a custom middleware for storing HTTP Requests in Django project i came across a trouble that WSGIRequest object is not JSON serializable. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
import json


class StoringHttpRequestsMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        print('Request looks like this - ')
        print json.dumps(request, separators=(',',':'))
        return
```

Should i perform parsing by myself or there are some ways to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you want to serialize the `request`?

Comment: I want to store it in json file afterwards. Should i perform some processing of request before serializing?

Comment: What is *in* the request that you want to store?

Comment: The whole request! I know it would be easy to create a model that will instantiate part of the request and save it to database but what if i want to save the whole requests?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can dump `request.__dict__` instead of request, but it's not give you full-depth representation of object.

Comment: Thnx. Finally i went this way and it was enough :)